# How can I implement the PHP output to a array with keys numbers

Tags: php, html

The output of the script is: 
"Outstanding 1... Outstanding 2... Outstanding 3..."

How can I output the for example only the second position of the array, so that I can output the results separately?

Like this: `$out[1]`

```
<?php
$html = '
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <section class="page single-review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="" itemprop="review">
            <article class="review clearfix">
                <div class="review-content">
                    <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    Outstanding 1... 
                    </div>
                    <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    Outstanding 2... 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
    Outstanding 3... 
    </div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML ($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query (".//div[@class='review-text']") as $review)
{
    $out = $review->nodeValue;
    echo $out;
}

?>
```

Comment: What keeps you from taking the second element of that array and perform whatever you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoul try something like this

```
<?php
$html = '
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <section class="page single-review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="" itemprop="review">
        <article class="review clearfix">
            <div class="review-content">
                <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    Outstanding 1...
                </div>
                <div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
                    Outstanding 2...
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="review-text" itemprop="reviewBody">
    Outstanding 3...
</div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML ($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);
$reviews = $xpath->query (".//div[@class='review-text']");

echo $reviews[1]->nodeValue; // Outstanding 2...
```

The point is to store all the reviews in an array and then echo the one you want from the array.

Comment: Ooops, I mispelled a variable.
Of courses you first added your own $html, yes ?

I edit so you have the full example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. Either add the entire query result to an array like this

```
$arr = $xpath->query (".//div[@class='review-text']")
```

and then call it by

```
$arr[1]->nodeValue
```

or if the HTML is big, you can really save memory by doing

```
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($xpath->query (".//div[@class='review-text']") as $review)
    {
        if ($counter == 1) {
            $out = $review->nodeValue;
            echo $out;
        }
        $counter++;
    }
```

Depending on what you need, you can pick one of the options. Also if you need to run other code, but the printing in the `foreach`, the second way can do that too.

Comment: This is not what I want. I will not Display the $out values in different Lines. I will bring the values to an array with key numbers. So that I can output only Outstanding 2.... or only Outstanding 3...

Comment: @Sinalco Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've edited with changes.

Comment: @Sinalco Please accept the answer then, so it can help other people with similar issue.

Comment: Sorry Martin, but the last answer from Will is the best answer to help other People.

Comment: @Sinalco I don't see how it is better for the general use. He is easier for exactly  your case, as you can just copy paste his entire answer, while I give different options that are not 100% for your answer only, while giving explanation, but after all, it is indeed your choice.

Comment: But your if Command can not work. Because the the $counter is never 1.

Comment: @Sinalco yes, you are right. I was focusing on the first solution. I have edited the answer to work.